# Extra data on a collection operation

Tags: api-platform.com

Does anybody know how to add extra data on a *collection*?
The doc says much about [how to add extra data on an item](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization#decorating-a-serializer-and-adding-extra-data) which translates into decorating the ItemNormalizer service, and it works pretty well.

But I’m struggling in finding out which normalizer to decorate when it comes to add some data on a collection of entities. The extra data could be anything: the current user logged in, a detailed pager, some debug parameters, ... that are not related to a specific entity, but rather on the request itself.

The only working solution for now is to hook on a Kernel event but that's definitely not the code I like to write:

```php
use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

final class SerializeListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $security;

    /**
     * @var NormalizerInterface
     */
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(
        Security $security,
        NormalizerInterface $normalizer
    ) {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function addCurrentUser(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if ($request->attributes->has('_api_respond')) {
            $serialized = $event->getControllerResult();
            $data = json_decode($serialized, true);
            $data['hydra:user'] = $this->normalizer->normalize(
                $this->security->getUser(),
                $request->attributes->get('_format'),
                $request->attributes->get('_api_normalization_context')
            );
            $event->setControllerResult(json_encode($data));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => [
                'addCurrentUser', 
                EventPriorities::POST_SERIALIZE,
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 5):

Alright, I finally managed to do this.

```php
namespace App\Api;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

final class ApiCollectionNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, NormalizerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var NormalizerInterface|NormalizerAwareInterface
     */
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        if (!$decorated instanceof NormalizerAwareInterface) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('The decorated normalizer must implement the %s.', NormalizerAwareInterface::class)
            );
        }
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {

        $data = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        if ('collection' === $context['operation_type'] && 'get' === $context['collection_operation_name']) {
            $data['hydra:meta'] = ['foo' => 'bar'];
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function setNormalizer(NormalizerInterface $normalizer)
    {
        $this->decorated->setNormalizer($normalizer);
    }

}
```

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Api\ApiCollectionNormalizer:
        decorates: 'api_platform.hydra.normalizer.collection'
        arguments: [ '@App\Api\ApiCollectionNormalizer.inner' ]
```

Keep it for the records :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's the better way that I found.